# Legendre symbol of $-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $x, y, n, p$ be positive integers such that

$$x^2 + ny^2 = p,$$

where $p$ is a prime such that $p \neq n$. I need to show that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{-n}{p}\right)=1$.

Comment: neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $p,$ if only because that would make $x^2 + n y^2$ strictly larger than $p.$

Comment: I now get that $x^2 = -ny^2 (mod p)$. Since $y$ and $p$ are relatively prime, we can multiply by the inverse of y and hence $-n = (xy')^2 (mod p)$ and hence is $-n$ a quadratic residue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one has shown an interest in this question for more than four years.